# Inner Div Pushing Outer Div

Tags: css, html, push, out

I've been trying to figure out this puzzle for the longest time. I'm trying to simulate a traditional HTML table tree structure using divs with table, tr and then td.

Firefox and Google Chrome behaves as I want but for some reason each CoreTableRow isn't getting pushed down to accommodate the height of the inner CoreTableCell divs in IE.

The below code is completely standalone, so please copy and paste into a blank html document to view:

```css
html, body, * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.CoreTable {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
}

div.CoreTable div.CoreTableRow {
  /*
  display:inline-block;
  display:block;
  */
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px dotted #0000AA;
}

div.CoreTable div.CoreTableRow div.CoreTableCell {
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!-- PINK -->

<div class="CoreTable" style="background-color: #FFEEEE;">
  <div class="CoreTableRow">
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="CoreTableRow">
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 200px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="CoreTableRow">
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px; background-color: #FFAAAA;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br />

<!-- GREEN -->

<div class="CoreTable" style="background-color: #EEFFEE;">
  <div class="CoreTableRow">
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="CoreTableRow">
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 200px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell">Lorem</div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px; background-color: #AAFFAA;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="CoreTableRow">
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="CoreTableCell" style="width: 300px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for anyone who can figure out this puzzle XD

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?  If the content will be tabular data, then tables are the right thing to do.

Comment: This was done in preparation for certain deprecation of table elements and attributes in HTML 5.

Comment: If you turn float off, it will automatically stop floating the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that your inner div is "overflowing" the containing/outer div,the solution would be adding "`overflow:auto;`" to the outer div (coreTable)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add "display:inline-block"

```css
.main{
  width:400px;
  background:red;
  }
.small{
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="small"></div>  
  <div class="small"></div>  
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>  
  <div class="small"></div>  
  <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```